# RestEasy client to secured service

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

We have deployed RestEasy services, as part of application, and secured them with filter (a class that implements `javax.servlet.Filter`). Filter checks if object of the User class exists in the session. The user object is inserted into session when user logs in. Everything works fine.

However, we need to create standalone app that accesses these services. We decided to use RestEasy client API. We can access these services if the filter is turned off, but how do we perform this logging in and session manipulation from RestEasy client API.

Comment: I don't understand your setup - the application has some REST endpoints that the client-facing javascript code can call? And now you have another client that doesn't acquire a session id before talking to your REST endpoint?

Comment: We have GWT web app that is already accessing REST services. Now we need standalone app that will access these same services.

Comment: Do you already have a service that allows you to login? Ie something that you POST a username/password to and that replies with a session id? If not, easiest way would be to create that and have the first call of your standalone app be to that service. All further calls need to supply that id.

Comment: Yes, we have such a service. The service's login method returns user object, while storing this object to HttpSession. As I said, servlet filter uses this object to filter unauthenticated request.

Could you provide code sample, how to supply this id into next service calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume your standalone client was written in Java.
Then a sample code would look like this.

First we need to authenticate the user by calling your auth service and obtain a valid session ID. Let's assume the obtained session id is equivalent to "**f47cdba8-d066-48e8-ad29-8c4222906bc7**". Then we can call the REST service with the valid session ID as a HTTP header parameter.

```
String url = "http://localhost:8081/AuthService/";

URL obj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

// optional default is GET
con.setRequestMethod("GET");

//add request header
con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "token=f47cdba8-d066-48e8-ad29-8c4222906bc7");

int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();

//print result
System.out.println(response.toString());
```

At the back end you need to process this HTTP header parameter based Session ID and validate the oncoming request before serving it.
Hope this helps.